# Ember: Call Action on Input Field on Focus Out with Argument

Tags: javascript, ember.js, input, helper, inline-editing

I'm creating a simple Todo App as I explore EmberJS v2.14.  I want to build in a manual inline editing feature--the user will double-click on a todo line item text span, to open up a input field.  The user will then edit the todo, which will be double bound to a backing object.  And then when focus is lost, the app will re-close the input field back to the newly edited text.

The following fragment of code is inside an `{{each}}` block helper, and it *almost* works.

```
{{#unless todo.isOpenForEdit}}
   <span {{action 'openForEditing' todo on='doubleClick'}}>{{todo.text}}</span>
{{else}}
  {{input type="text" value=todo.text action='closeForEditing' on='focus-out'}}
{{/unless}}
```

**Working Pieces**

- I can double click to go to editing mode (i.e. `openForEditing()` is correctly called with the write argument.)
- the action handler `closeForEditing()` is correctly called when focus is lost from the input field.

**Pieces Not Working**

- I don't know how to pass the todo object model as an argument, so
  that the `closeForEditing()` handler can do the appropriate work of setting
  `isOpenForEdit` back to false.

--

**Q)** How do I pass an argument to an action handler while working with the input helper?

**Q)** Is there a different approach I can take, to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your action in following way:

```
 {{input type="text" value=todo.text focusOut=(action 'closeForEditing' todo)}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble finding what I needed in the docs.

Comment: @MichaelR This type of action is known as a closure action and is covered in [this section](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/#toc_passing-arguments) of the guides.

Answer (score 2):

You can curry `todo` by creating closure action using action helper

```
{{input type="text" value=todo.text action=(action 'closeForEditing' todo) on='focus-out'}}
```

Comment: Actually I just used your example by currying required arguments, but you dont need to do `action=(action 'closeForEditing' todo) on='focus-out'' instead you can simply say `focusOut=(action 'closeForEditing' todo)` like in the answer mentioned above.

Comment: @MichaelR In your case, you are iterating `todo` so I believe this will be property of the particular component so instead of passing you can just say `let todo=this.get('todo')` in closeForEditing function.